# Leave out few commits in a new GIT branch

Tags: git

I want to create a new branch from the `master` branch, which has all but a few commits which I don't want in the new branch.

These commits in `master` are not the last few commits but somewhere down the branch history.

**What's the best way to achieve this?**

One way I know of is to go to the last 'good' commit in `master`, create a new branch from there, and then `cherry-pick` all the commits I want in this new branch.

But this process can be time-consuming. Is there a better, shorter way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I skip commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128473/how-can-i-skip-commits-in-git)

Comment: I tried Interactive Rebase as I thought it might work, but I couldn't figure out how to move between commits in terminal to pick/remove them.